# Execute a controller after main controller is executed

Tags: angularjs

I have an index page `index.html` with its controller `indexController`. I set some value($scope.ipAddress) in a `factory` in the `indexController` which is used by other controllers of the html inside `ng-view`.

When the page is loaded, the `indexController` is supposed to execute first, set a value in the `factory` and then that value is used by other controllers of pages inside `ng-view`.

But I think the other controllers are executed first before `indexController` and I get undefined for the value I set.

This is the `indexController` with `factory`:

```
        angular.module('tollApp')
.controller('indexController', function($scope,$http,$window,userDetailsFactory){
    $scope.usernameFromServer={};
    $scope.getUserDetails = function(){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'http://192.168.1.80:4000/getUserDetails'
            // url:'http://websitename.com/getUserDetails'
        })
        .then(function(response){

            // console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            userDetailsFactory.setUserDetailsInFactory(response.data);
        $scope.usernameFromFactory = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().usernameFromSession;
        $scope.theIP = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().ipAddress;
            // $scope.usernameFromServer = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().username;
            // console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.usernameFromFactory)+"usernameFromFactory");
        })
    }
    $scope.logout = function(request,response){
        $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/logout'
        })
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
            if(response.data=="logout"){
                // $window.location.href="http://websitename.comlogin";
                $window.location.href="http://192.168.1.80:4000/login";

            }
        })
    }
    console.log("indexController");
}).factory('userDetailsFactory',function(){
    var user = {};
    return {
        setUserDetailsInFactory : function(val){
            user.useridFromSession = val[0].UserID;
            user.usernameFromSession = val[0].UserName;
            user.userroleFromSession = val[0].UserRole;
            user.clientidFromSession = val[0].ClientID;
             user.ipAddress = "http://192.168.1.80:4000/";
            // user.ipAddress = "http://websitename.com/";
            // console.log("in set "+user.clientidFromSession);
        },
        getUserDetailsFromFactory : function(){
            return user;
        }
    };
})
```

The other controller where I use the value from factory:

```
$scope.ipForHttp = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().ipAddress;
console.log($scope.ipForHttp); //undefined
$scope.loading = false;
$scope.ClientID = userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory().clientidFromSession;
// $scope.dev={};

$scope.getDevice =function(){
    console.log($scope.ipForHttp); //undefined
    $scope.loading = true;

      $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : $scope.ipForHttp+"getDeviceDetailsReport"
      }).then(function mySucces(response) {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at your `$scope.getUserDetails` - you're using `$http` ([docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)) service to make an asycronous AJAX call to the back-end.

The callback function you supply in the `.then()` method of the returned object may be executed sometime in the future or may even not - depends on whether the call succeeds or fails. You must not expect it to behave syncronously, because it never will, even if the backend responds instantly.

That's why you can't expect to have the desired data in your other controllers and need to adjust your code accordingly, e.g.

```
// tells angular to execute watcher function on every $digest
$scope.$watch(function () {
    // watches the returned value of the service's method
    return userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory();
}, function (newVal) {
    // filtering out empty object
    if (!Object.keys(newVal).length) {
        return;
    }

    // the following code will be run when
    // userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory
    // returns some value
    // in our particular case - after getting
    // data from backend and setting it in
    // userDetailsFactory.setUserDetailsFromFactory

    $scope.loading = false;
    $scope.ipForHttp = newVal.ipAddress;
    $scope.ClientID = newVal.clientidFromSession;

    $scope.getDevice();
},
// tells angular to watch properties of the object too
true);
```

Optionally, if you need to execute that code only once when user details are set, do this

```
var unbindUserDetailsWatcher = $scope.$watch(function () {
    return userDetailsFactory.getUserDetailsFromFactory();
}, function (newVal) {
    if (!Object.keys(newVal).length) {
        return;
    }

    unbindUserDetailsWatcher();
    unbindUserDetailsWatcher = null;

    ...
});
```

Comment: OP, there is a much better way of solving this task - using service and Promises ([$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to be exact). You should take a look at the docs and examples and try to figure it out for yourself. Hint -  the code that has mutliple dependants should be moved to the server. If you need any help with that - just comment and I'll show guide you to the correct solution.

Comment: It is the code that's supposed to go to the "other controller", I'll add comments to the code to make it easier for you to understand

Comment: The `newValue` is empty when I `console.log()`. It is `{}`. I have set a `timeout` on `indeController`(controller where I set the value in factory). so that it simulates my problem stated above which occurs only when I host. When I remove the `timeout`, I get all values.

Comment: also did you mean to type `newValue` instead of `newVal` in these lines above? `$scope.ipForHttp = newVal.ipAddress;
    $scope.ClientID = newVal.clientidFromSession;`

Comment: ow yeah, my bad. was sleepy when answering your question and made a few mistakes, gonna fix `em now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127091/discussion-between-dennis-and-iliveinapineappleunderthesea).

Comment: hi..both your answer and `$q` worked, but I "sometimes" dont see the table that I display with pagination when I refresh. it works with `ng-init`. I see the other content in the page but the table part shows for a second and then disappears. I use this for pagination: https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/ . can you tell me what i can do

Comment: Create a new question and someone will help you. This is out of scope of this one.